# Error With Cgridview 'filter' Property, Error Code ::has No Method 'querystring'

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm having problem with the filter functionality in CGridview. The filter box doesn't works at all. Nothing happens when i type something, and hit enter.

Here is the view code selectproducts.php ::

```
<div id="shortcodes" class="page">
<div class="container">

    <!-- Title Page -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="title-page">
                <h2 class="title">Available Products</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Title Page -->



    <!-- Start Product Section -->
    <div class="row">


        <?php


        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id' => 'products-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filter' => $dataProvider->model,
            'ajaxUpdate' => TRUE,
            'pager' => array(
                'header' => '',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'maxButtonCount' => 25,
                'selectedPageCssClass' => 'active',
                'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
                'firstPageCssClass' => 'previous',
                'lastPageCssClass' => 'next',
                'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
                'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
                'prevPageLabel' => '<',
                'nextPageLabel' => '>',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                'id',
                array(
                  'name' => 'name',

                ),
                'category',
                'brand',
                'weight_unit',
                'price_unit',
                'flavors',
                array(
                    'name' => 'providers',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="provider-label label label-info"><a href="http://www.'.$data->providers. '">'. $data->providers .'</a></div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>

    </div>
    <!-- End Product Section -->


</div>
```

Here is the relevant action in ProductsController that is rendering this view. The $dataprovider variable in the view is a CActiveDataProvider object which holds the result of a conditional query.

```
public function actionDropdown() {

    if (isset($_GET["Dropdown"])) {
        $dropdownData = $_GET["Dropdown"];
        $this->category = $dropdownData["category"];
        $this->price = $dropdownData["price"];
    }
    // separate the price text into min and max value
    $priceText = explode(" - ", $this->price);  



    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('category', $this->category, true);

    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('price', substr($priceText[0], 1), substr($priceText[1], 1), 'AND');

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Products', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 'price_unit, name',
        ),
    ));


    $this->render('selectproducts', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

And here is the Products() model search() function ::

```
public function search()
    {
            // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
            $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
            $criteria->compare('category',$this->category,true);
            $criteria->compare('brand',$this->brand,true);
            $criteria->compare('weight',$this->weight,true);
            $criteria->compare('weight_unit',$this->weight_unit,true);
            $criteria->compare('price',$this->price,true);
            $criteria->compare('price_unit',$this->price_unit,true);
            $criteria->compare('flavors',$this->flavors,true);
            $criteria->compare('providers',$this->providers,true);

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
    }
```

Now, when i hit enter in the filter box, i'm getting this error, which is logged in firebug

```
TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

options.url = $.param.querystring(options.url, options.data);

In file jquery.yiigridview.js
```

Does anyone knows what is causing this error. I just can't figure out what is causing this. And i also don't know what modification should i do in jquery.yiigridview.js to fix this error.

Thanks in advance.
Maxx

**EDIT**

After suggestion from tinyByte below. I tried to move the CActiveDataProvider logic to the model, so that i can use $model->search() in the GridView 'dataProvider' property, but it didn't helped still the same error.

Here are the codes

Controller:::

```
public function actionDropdown() {

    $dataProvider = new Products;

    if (isset($_GET["Dropdown"])) {
        $dropdownData = $_GET["Dropdown"];
        $this->category = $dropdownData["category"];
        $this->price = $dropdownData["price"];
    }


    $this->render('selectproducts', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'price' => $this->price,
        //'num' => $this->numResults,
    ));
}
```

Here is the model ::

```
public function searchDropdown($category, $price) {

    $this->priceText = explode(" - ", $price);  

    $this->criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $this->criteria->compare('category', $category, true);

    $this->criteria->addBetweenCondition('price', substr($this->priceText[0], 1), substr($this->priceText[1], 1), 'AND');

    return new CActiveDataProvider('Products', array(
        'criteria' => $this->criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 25,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 'price_unit, name',
        ),
    ));



}
```

And here is the view ::

```
<div id="shortcodes" class="page">
<div class="container">

    <!-- Title Page -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="title-page">
                <h2 class="title">Available Products</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Title Page -->



    <!-- Start Product Section -->
    <div class="row">


        <?php


        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id' => 'products-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->searchDropdown($category, $price),
            'filter' => $dataProvider,
            'ajaxUpdate' => TRUE,
            'pager' => array(
                'header' => '',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'maxButtonCount' => 25,
                'selectedPageCssClass' => 'active',
                'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
                'firstPageCssClass' => 'previous',
                'lastPageCssClass' => 'next',
                'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
                'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
                'prevPageLabel' => '<',
                'nextPageLabel' => '>',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'id',
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                  'name' => 'name',


                ),
                'category',
                'brand',
                'weight_unit',
                'price_unit',
                'flavors',
                array(
                    'name' => 'providers',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="provider-label label label-info"><a href="http://www.'.$data->providers. '">'. $data->providers .'</a></div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>

    </div>
    <!-- End Product Section -->


</div>
```

Still its not working. i.e. Nothing happens when i type something in the filter box and hit enter. The same error comes up ::

In Firebug

```
TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

options.url = $.param.querystring(options.url, options.data);

In file jquery.yiigridview.js
```

And in Chrome i get a slightly more descriptive error message.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){var r,i=[],o=function(e,t)

{t=x.isFunction(t)?t():null==t?"":t,i[i.length]=encodeURIComponent(e)+"="+encodeURIComponent(t)};if(n===t&&(n=x.ajaxSettings&&

x.ajaxSettings.traditional),x.isArray(e)||e.jquery&&!x.isPlainObject(e))x.each(e,function(){o(this.name,this.value)});
else for(r in e)gn(r,e[r],n,o);return i.join("&").replace(cn,"+")} 

has no method 'querystring' 

jquery.yiigridview.js:310
```

I just can't figure out what to do.

**EDIT**

Ok after long struggle i somehow managed to get rid of the error, with the help of a fellow forum mate at Yii forum [http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47904-error-with-cgridview-filter-property-error-code-has-no-method-querystring/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_224169](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47904-error-with-cgridview-filter-property-error-code-has-no-method-querystring/page__view__findpost__p__224169).

Here is what i added.

```
 <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.jquery.ajaxqueue.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.treeview.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.treeview.async.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.treeview.edit.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.yii.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.yiiactiveform.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/jquery.yiitab.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl; ?>/28e7347b/punycode.js"></script>
```

The error went away but the filter is still not working. The ajax load icon shows for less than a second and then nothing happens. I also see the correct search parameter being passed in the array.

Here is the array which i'm seeing being passed

```
Dropdown[category]  Chant Books
Dropdown[price] $340 - $476
Products[brand] 
Products[category]  
Products[flavors]   
Products[name]  Owl Chant Scroll
Products[price_unit]    
Products[providers] 
Products[weight_unit]   
Products_page   1
ajax    products-grid
yt0
```

Comment: So does anyone knows a fix for this. I'm literally stuck endlessly with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id' => 'products-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $model->customeSearch(), // add your method of search here
            'filter' => $model, // for validation
             'ajaxUrl'=> Yii::app()->request->getUrl(),
            ...
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the reason for this error is jQuery conflict: there is one you load, and another one loaded by cgridview.
The solution is to remove your jquery, or if you must have it - remove the Yii's one:

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
    'jquery.js'=>false,
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also added `$cs->coreScriptPosition = CClientScript::POS_END;` after that because otherwise there was an error  in script due to loading jQuery after loading a plugin so jQuery was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The filter attribute is for validation, you need to provide a search function for attribute "dataprovider" of your grid

```
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id' => 'products-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->customeSearch(), // add your method of search here
        'filter' => $model, // for validation
        ...
        'columns' => array(
             array(
               'name' => 'someCol',
               'value' => '$data->someCol',
               'filter' => CHtml::dropdownList( ... ), // put an input here for your filter
             ),
```

),

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I tried to apply your advice but its still giving me the same error. Check out the edit above. I think it has something to do with the javascript file jquery.yiigridview.js. But i can't figure out what modification should i do to that file to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Well at last the problem is solved. It turned out that i needed to add the ajaxUpdate and the ajaxURL property of the Gridview widget. And make another action for the ajax filter.

```
'ajaxUpdate' => 'products-grid',
            'ajaxUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('products/UpdateGrid'),
```

Anyways here are the code, which works now.

the action methods in the products controller ::

```
public function actionDropdown() {

    /*
     * create the session to store the dropdown variables
     * 
     * 
     */

    $this->session = new CHttpSession;
    $this->session->open();

    $dataProvider = new Products;
    $products = new Products('search');
    $products->unsetAttributes();

    if (isset($_GET["Dropdown"])) {
        $dropdownData = $_GET["Dropdown"];
        $this->category = $dropdownData["category"];
        $this->price = $dropdownData["price"];

        $this->session["category"] = $this->category;
        $this->session["price"] = $this->price;
    }

    if (isset($_GET["Products"])) {
        $products->attributes = $_GET["Products"];
    }

    $this->render('selectproducts', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'products' => $products,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'price' => $this->price,
            //'num' => $this->numResults,
    ));
}

public function actionUpdateGrid() {

    $products = new Products;

    $products->unsetAttributes();


    if (isset($_GET["Products"])) {
        $products->attributes = $_GET["Products"];

    }




    $this->renderPartial('_selectproducts', array(
        'products' => $products,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'price' => $this->price,

    ));

}
```

The Product model code::

```
/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);
    $criteria->compare('category', $this->category, true);
    $criteria->compare('brand', $this->brand, true);
    $criteria->compare('weight', $this->weight, true);
    $criteria->compare('weight_unit', $this->weight_unit, true);
    $criteria->compare('price', $this->price, true);
    $criteria->compare('price_unit', $this->price_unit, true);
    $criteria->compare('flavors', $this->flavors, true);
    $criteria->compare('providers', $this->providers, true);




    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Products the static model class
 */
public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

/*
 * Dropdown search
 * 
 * 
 */

public function searchDropdown($category, $price) {

    $this->priceText = explode(" - ", $price);

    $this->criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $this->criteria->compare('category', $category, true);

    $this->criteria->addBetweenCondition('price', substr($this->priceText[0], 1), substr($this->priceText[1], 1), 'AND');

    return new CActiveDataProvider('Products', array(
        'criteria' => $this->criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 25,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 'price_unit, name',
        ),
    ));
}

public function searchGrid() {

    $session = new CHttpSession;
    $session->open();


    $category = $session["category"];


    $this->criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $this->priceText = explode(" - ", $session["price"]);
    $this->criteria->compare('category', $category, true);

    $this->criteria->addBetweenCondition('price', substr($this->priceText[0], 1), substr($this->priceText[1], 1), 'AND');

    /*
     * 
     * compare the names to see if the flavor or weight is present
     * 
     */

    $this->criteria->compare('name', $this->flavors, TRUE);
    $this->criteria->compare('name', $this->weight, TRUE);

    $this->criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $this->criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('category', $this->category, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('brand', $this->brand, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('weight', $this->weight, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('weight_unit', $this->weight_unit, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('price', $this->price, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('price_unit', $this->price_unit, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('flavors', $this->flavors, true);
    $this->criteria->compare('providers', $this->providers, true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $this->criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 25,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 'price_unit, name',
        ),
    ));

}
```

And the views::

view name::- selectproducts.php

```
<div id="shortcodes" class="page">
<div class="container">

    <!-- Title Page -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="title-page">
                <h2 class="title">Available Products</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Title Page -->



    <!-- Start Product Section -->
    <div class="row">


        <?php
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id' => 'products-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->searchDropdown($category, $price),
            'filter' => $products,
            'ajaxUpdate' => 'products-grid',
            'ajaxUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('products/UpdateGrid'),
            'pager' => array(
                'header' => '',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'maxButtonCount' => 25,
                'selectedPageCssClass' => 'active',
                'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
                'firstPageCssClass' => 'previous',
                'lastPageCssClass' => 'next',
                'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
                'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
                'prevPageLabel' => '<',
                'nextPageLabel' => '>',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="custom-badge">' . $data->name . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'category',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->category . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'brand',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->brand . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'weight_unit',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->weight_unit . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                 array(
                    'name' => 'price_unit',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-price-glow">' . $data->price_unit . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'flavors',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->flavors . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'providers',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="provider-label label label-info"><a href="http://www.' . $data->providers . '">' . $data->providers . '</a></div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>

    </div>
    <!-- End Product Section -->


</div>
```

view name::- _selectproducts.php

```
<?php

        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id' => 'products-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $products->searchGrid($category, $price),
            'filter' => $products,
            'ajaxUpdate' => TRUE,
            'pager' => array(
                'header' => '',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'maxButtonCount' => 25,
                'selectedPageCssClass' => 'active',
                'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
                'firstPageCssClass' => 'previous',
                'lastPageCssClass' => 'next',
                'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
                'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
                'prevPageLabel' => '<',
                'nextPageLabel' => '>',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="custom-badge">' . $data->name . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'category',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->category . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'brand',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->brand . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'weight_unit',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->weight_unit . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                 array(
                    'name' => 'price_unit',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-price-glow">' . $data->price_unit . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'flavors',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="grid-glow">' . $data->flavors . '</div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'providers',
                    'value' => function($data) {
                        return '<div class="provider-label label label-info"><a href="http://www.' . $data->providers . '">' . $data->providers . '</a></div>';
                    },
                    'type' => 'raw',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>
```

Well as you see the ajax filter needed a new action method which will render a partial view containing just the result grid.
I hope it helps someone who is stuck with the same error.

Thanks,
Maxx

Answer (score 0):

Refresh yii js files.In config:

```
'components'=>array(

    'clientScript' => array(
        'packages' => array(
            'jquery' => array(
                'baseUrl' => 'js',
                'js' => array(
                    'jquery-1.10.2.js', 
                    'jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js',
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function

[Break On This Error]

`options.url = $.param.querystring(options.url, options.data);`

In file `jquery.yiigridview.js`

I have also faced the same problem reported above and it is very easy to resolve. It usually happens when the jQuery you have included conflicts the default js added by `jquery.yiigridview.js`.

Try simply removing the min.js that you have included, it will work absolutely fine.